# How to complete function before ViewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uiviewcontroller

I'm fairly certain my function to get data from Firebase is working correctly, however I can't display the data in the ViewController. It seems the View is rendered before the function is completed.

I need help figuring out how to run the function before the view is rendered.

This is the code in the viewController

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import Kingfisher

class activityVC: UIViewController {

    // Variables passed from feedVC
    var activityId = ""

    @IBOutlet weak var distance: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var time: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var elevation: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var kills: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sightings: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ration_shot_sightings: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var activityImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Get userdata from Firebase
        DataService.instance.getActivityData(activityId: activityId) { (activityData) in
            print("activity data dump in ViewController")
            dump(activityData)
            if activityData.isEmpty == false {
                print("Data is coming")
                // if data exist populate textfields with information from database
                self.kills.text = activityData[0].name
                self.sightings.text = String(activityData[0].sightingCount)
                print("SightingsCount: \(activityData[0].sightingCount)")
                self.kills.text = String(activityData[0].killCount)
                self.sightings.text = String(activityData[0].sightingCount)

                if activityData[0].defaultImageURL.isEmpty == false {
                    self.activityImageView.kf.setImage(with: URL.init(string:activityData[0].defaultImageURL))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // ----------------------------
    // IBActions
    // ----------------------------
    @IBAction func backBtnWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        // Navigates back to feedVC
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

This is the DataService function that it runs (note I've slimmed down the function so not all variables are there)

```
// Get data on specific activity
    func getActivityData(activityId: String, handler: @escaping (_ activities: [Activity]) -> ()) {

        var activityData = [Activity]()

        REF_ACTIVITY.child(activityId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            guard let activity = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary else { return }

            let activityId =            activityId
            let name =                  activity["name"] as? String ?? ""
            let description =           activity["description"] as? String ?? ""

            let userId =                activity["userId"] as? String ?? ""

            let tempKillCount =         activity["killCount"] as? NSNumber ?? 0
            let killCount =             Int(tempKillCount)

            let tempSightingCount =     activity["sightingCount"] as? NSNumber ?? 0
            let sightingCount =         Int(tempSightingCount)


            let data = Activity(activityId: activityId, name: name, userId: userId, killCount: killCount, sightingCount: sightingCount)
                activityData.append(data)
                print("Within function - print activityData: ")
                dump(activityData)
            }
            handler(activityData)
    }
```

Comment: Hide all your labels and add an activity indicator until the data loads then show your labels with the data from firebase when they are loaded. And just make a test if the call to firebase has been timed out call the data from the database.

Comment: what you get from `dump(activityData)`

Comment: @Ali: the activityData is empty (- 0 elements)

Comment: so if your `activityData` is empty how you expect to display the data ? `activityData` empty means you have no data

Comment: @Ali That is a good point - I just don't understand why its empty - if I dump the "activityData" within the function then it give the expected data. But if I do it in the ViewController it is empty. In the terminal the function dump is written after the dump in the ViewController. - based on this I assumed that the function is run after the viewController

Comment: @Chris_1983_Norway i figure it out , check the answer in minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to move the call to your closure (handler) in side  the observe listener

`observeSingleEvent` is async which means it will return immediately  then this line will executed `handler(activityData)` and at that moment `activityData` is empty

```
func getActivityData(activityId: String, handler: (activities: [Activity]) -> Void ) 
{

    var activityData = [Activity]()

    REF_ACTIVITY.child(activityId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) 
    { 
        (snapshot) in

        guard let activity = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary else { return }

        let activityId =            activityId
        let name =                  activity["name"] as? String ?? ""
        let description =           activity["description"] as? String ?? ""
        let userId =                activity["userId"] as? String ?? ""
        let tempKillCount =         activity["killCount"] as? NSNumber ?? 0
        let killCount =             Int(tempKillCount)
        let tempSightingCount =     activity["sightingCount"] as? NSNumber ?? 0
        let sightingCount =         Int(tempSightingCount)


        let data = Activity(activityId: activityId, name: name, userId: userId, killCount: killCount, sightingCount: sightingCount)
        activityData.append(data)
        print("Within function - print activityData: ")
        dump(activityData)

        handler(activityData)

    }   

}
```

Comment: never even considered that the handler(activityData) was in the wrong place. Thanks a million for helping me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with loading the data and once it's complete push your new VC setted with downloaded data but this is not a good UX one good way to do is Cover the view of the VC with a loading indicator until the request finish and remove the activity indicator and set the data to the labels